# How many editions of the "Authorised Daily Prayer Book" have there been?

Tags: history, prayer-book

Background:  many years ago, while studying in the UK, I bought a pocket-sized, softcover edition of "The Authorised Daily Prayer Book of the United Hebrew Congregations of the Commonwealth".  This was in 1994 or 1995; as it was published before Princess Diana died, the "Prayer for the Royal Family" included references not only to "Our sovereign lady, Queen Elizabeth" and "Elizabeth, the Queen Mother" but also to both the Prince of Wales and the Princess of Wales.  (This is from memory; unfortunately, I lost the siddur some time in the early 2000s, so I no longer have it in my collection.)

The recent death of Queen Elizabeth and the ascension of Charles to the throne means, I suppose, that future editions of the Authorised Daily Prayer Book will include a new version the "Prayer for the Royal Family".  This has me wondering:  How many different editions of the Authorised Prayer Book have there been?  Did they issue a new version every time there was a change in the Royal Family?  For example, did they revise it when Charles and Diana divorced, and then again after her death?  What about when Charles was born, or when the Queen Mother died?  Apart from the "Prayer for the Royal Family", what other changes are there between the different editions?  Is there a comprehensive list somewhere of all the different editions, including publication dates and what changes are found in each?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Partial answer: According to [this listing](http://policeboxes.com/ajc/adpb.htm) by a person who has been collecting all editions, there are 33 editions as of 2006, with further printings without changes from later years. Another edition was supposed to have come out in 2021.
I will note that in 1962 and 1990 the numbering system was renewed, so the number 33 is reached by adding the new editions to the old counting.

In the link you can also see the differences between the Royal Family prayers in each edition, including the American edition which had a prayer for the President.

Comment: We all consult HaRav Google as needed, but I am still extremely impressed you were able to find this information. Chazak u baruch, @Harel!

Comment: @יהושעק Mohara"r Google led me to Chacham Wikipedia which linked to that site. No big deal...